# Error when trying to scrape videos from TikTok using a hashtag

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, tiktok-api

I'm trying to scrape videos from tiktok using the unofficial tiktokAPI. But, I keep getting a JSONDecodeError.

This is the code I'm using. The problem is starting in the for loop.

```
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi

with TikTokApi() as api:
  
  tag = api.hashtag(name="dogsoftiktok")

  print(tag.info())

  for video in tag.videos():
    print(video.id)
```

This is the error I'm getting.

```
 raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

It's supposed to print the video id for all the videos using the hashtag.

Answer (score 0):

as [github-issue](https://github.com/davidteather/TikTok-Api/issues/976), this method stopped working.

You might try @Russell-Newton his [answer](https://github.com/davidteather/TikTok-Api/issues/976#issuecomment-1368068039)

> For anyone still needing to get around this issue, I'm working on [my own library](https://github.com/Russell-Newton/TikTokPy) that does work with getting videos under a tag. You don't need to preload any cookies because it doesn't handle API calls in the same way. I have yet to need to provide a proxy for bulk scraping. The methodology to get a large number of videos from a tag or user or comments under a video is handled a bit different, but this is [explained in the documentation](https://tiktokpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/explanation.html#data-collection). I am actively working on the development of the library and am open to issues and contributions.

Or @mesaleh his [answer](https://github.com/davidteather/TikTok-Api/issues/976#issuecomment-1320790295)

> This works
>
> ```py
> def test_search(keyword, offset=0):
>     params = {
>         'keyword': keyword,
>         'offset': offset,
>     }
>     cookies = {
>         'ttwid': '** REDACTED **',
>         'sessionid': '** REDACTED **',
>     }
>     request = requests.get("http://us.tiktok.com/api/search/item/full/", params=params, cookies=cookies)
>     return(request.json())
>
> print(test_search("#rstats"))
> ```